# Getting the default computed CSS styles of an element while hovering over it

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I'm trying to build a tool that collects the CSS styles of any element on a webpage. The problem that's happening is that you need to hover over the element in order to select it, but while doing this it triggers the :hover state.

Ideally I want to collect both the default and the :hover styles and this seems to be possible by passing a psuedo-element with getComputedStyle. The way I'm hoping to do this, if it's possible is by temporarily disabling :hover, then getting the default state and hover state directly through getComputedStyle. I've tried giving the element a CSS property of `pointer-events: none` while hovering over it, but this acts very strangely and won't allow the element to be selected, only the parent elements.

This is a small snippet of code that I'm using at the moment.

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    var targetElement = e.target;
    var allStyles = getComputedStyle(e.target);
});
```

I have also tried and collected an element's classList, getting all the CSS styles applied to those classes - but for any one property 'background-color', for example - there are multiple conflicting styles and I don't know which is actually applied to the element. Is there a way to check this or a way to temporarily disable the hover state?

Thanks a lot for taking a look!

Answer (score 1):

Use the targets [`relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget)

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "foo") {
    console.clear();
    const currentStyle = getComputedStyle(evt.relatedTarget);
    console.log(currentStyle.color, currentStyle.cursor);
  }
}
```

```css
#foo {
  margin: 2rem;
}

#foo:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Hi there</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for a couple of elements on a site, but it was only getting the default style when I moved the mouse outside of the element.

I ended up iterating through all styleSheets and just removing any rules with the :hover element. I'm thinking about how to get the :hover CSS and thought you could store these rules and match the target element's class with the rule's selectorText.